# COPY in cqlsh of Cassandra Table Column Truncating data type double

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I am copying a table between two exact table configs but different names with the CQLSH COPY command in cassandra.

**Example:**

```
COPY "my"."data"(number) TO 'export.csv';
COPY "my"."datacopy"(number) FROM 'export.csv';
```

The column i'm copying is of type double.  The problem is it appears that the copy is truncating the precision of the column.

For example:

**Original Data:**

> 5.084936038014788E8

**After Copy**

> 5.0849E8

How can I maintain the 64 bit precision when copying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cqlsh has an [option controlling float precision](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.3/bin/cqlsh.py#L2387-L2388) for formatting. You can set it in your cqlshrc:

```
[ui]
float_precision=12
```

(normally ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc)